# ็How to prevent heroku sleeping mode by python code

Tags: python, heroku, dialogflow-es

I do chatbot on Dialogflow and connect Heroku with python in Github. How can I prevent Heroku from sleeping by python? Could you share the code with me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Free Plan you cannot prevent the Dyno to sleep (after 30 min inactivity).

There is a workaround if your Chatbot runs on a web site: in this case you could send a dummy request (just to start the Dyno) to your webhook hosted on Heroku when the user access the page, for example

```
<body onload="wakeUpCall();">


<script language="javascript">
  function wakeUpCall() {
    var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    xhr2.open("GET", "https://mywebhook.herokuapp.com/", true);
  xhr2.send(null);
  }
</script>
```

It is not obviously a perfect approach (it works only if you control the client and it relies on the Dyno starting before the chatbot sends data to the webhook), but it is an option if you want to keep working with the Free plan.

Comment: This would go on the web page hosting your BOT. Which client do you use? How do you chat to your chatbot?

Answer (score 0):

First some things to keep in mind before you try to use the free dyno for something it wasn't intended to be used for:

1. Heroku provides 1000 free hours a month. This is enough to only run single Heroku dyno at the free tier level. If you need to avoid the startup delay for two apps, then you'll need to pay for at least one of them.
2. Heroku still only allows for a single free dyno to run on your app. This you might lose traffic when you you are pushing new code (since the free web down has to shut down so you can built a new one).
3. There are undoubtably other issues as well, but those are the main ones I can think of offhand.

Now the solution:

Really, you just need something to ping your site at least once every 30 minutes. You could write a script for this, but there is an extremely useful tool that already does something like this that provides more benefit to you.

That would be the Availability (or Uptime) Monitoring tool. This is a tool that ensures your site is  "still up and running" by pinging a URL every X minutes and ensuring that the response is a valid, expected response (IE: 200 status code and/or checking for certain text on the page). These often also provide the benefit of contacting you if it receives unexpected response (almost certainly an error) for too long.

Here is an example of an availability monitor:
https://uptimerobot.com/